# Betamax with Spring Boot throws Illegal use of nonvirtual function call

Tags: groovy, spring-boot, spock, betamax

I'm trying to setup a simple test in Groovy with Spock using Betamax:

```
class BetaMaxSpockTest extends Specification {

    @Rule
    public Recorder recorder = new Recorder()

    @Betamax(tape = "some_tape")
    def 'You shall pass'() {
        expect:
        true
    }
}
```

I'm also using Spring Boot so I have spring-boot-starter-parent as my parent in pom.xml:

```
<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>1.2.6.RELEASE</version>
</parent>
```

When I run above test I'm getting this error:

```
java.lang.VerifyError: (class: co/freeside/betamax/proxy/jetty/BetamaxProxy, method: super$3$getBean signature: (Ljava/lang/Class;)Ljava/lang/Object;) Illegal use of nonvirtual function call
at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:264)
at co.freeside.betamax.proxy.jetty.ProxyServer.start(ProxyServer.groovy:47)
at co.freeside.betamax.Recorder.startProxy(Recorder.groovy:198)
at co.freeside.betamax.Recorder.withTape(Recorder.groovy:167)
at co.freeside.betamax.Recorder$1.evaluate(Recorder.groovy:185)
at org.spockframework.runtime.extension.builtin.MethodRuleInterceptor.intercept(MethodRuleInterceptor.java:40)
at org.spockframework.runtime.extension.MethodInvocation.proceed(MethodInvocation.java:84)
at org.spockframework.util.ReflectionUtil.invokeMethod(ReflectionUtil.java:138)
at org.spockframework.util.ReflectionUtil.invokeMethod(ReflectionUtil.java:138)
at org.spockframework.util.ReflectionUtil.invokeMethod
```

Without Spring Boot on path it works fine. Looks like some versions problem. Anyone had similar issue?

My full pom.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>com.test</groupId>
    <artifactId>test</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>

    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>1.2.6.RELEASE</version>
    </parent>

    <properties>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
        <!--plugins versions-->
        <maven.compiler.plugin.version>3.3</maven.compiler.plugin.version>
        <!--settings-->
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <!--Spring Boot-->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <!--Spock Testing-->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.spockframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spock-core</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <!--Groovy Testing-->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.codehaus.groovy</groupId>
            <artifactId>groovy-all</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <!--Betamax Http Mocks-->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>co.freeside</groupId>
            <artifactId>betamax</artifactId>
            <version>1.1.2</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>

        <pluginManagement>
            <--...-->
        </pluginManagement>
    </build>
</project>
```

Comment: @tim_yates <java.version>1.8</java.version>

Comment: Yeah, I can see that....  But which build of 1.8?  u60?

Comment: Java version - build 1.8.0_45-b14
@Opal, I'm not using gradle.

Comment: Have you tried the latest jdk? I know verify errors have been a thing with some versions of 1.8

Comment: Updated Java to (build 1.8.0_60-b27) but nothing changed..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found the solution. The problem was in wrong versions of jetty and httpclient. BetaMax requires versions shown below, while Spring's parent pom declares much newer versions.

Adding this two lines to properties in my pom.xml solved the issue:

```
<jetty.version>7.3.1.v20110307</jetty.version>
<httpclient.version>4.2.1</httpclient.version>
```

Anyway, thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple things you can do to fix this. The first is that you can make the code in question `@CompileStatic` (probably the Spec in your case) which often resolves the issue, but this is not always desireable (and does not always work).

The other thing you can do is add `-Xverify:none` to your java command line options (wherever you would specify them for your environment). This will turn off the verification, which is what is causing the error.

From what I have read about this issue when I originally ran into it, they are planning on turning off verification by default in the next Java version. This generally occurs with Groovy or other libraries that do a lot of bytecode manipulation under the covers (asm is another).